# digital ocean error code 1 Non-Zero Exit while deploying a project

Tags: angular, deployment, build, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy a small project I developed using .NET in C# and angular, with digital ocean but I get this error at the build phase.

**here is the log:**

occurred:
Invalid configuration object.    Webpack has been initialised using
a configuration object that does    not match the API schema.
2022-03-04T12:03:27.319208660Z  -    configuration.entry['styles']
should not contain the item
'/workspace/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
twice.    2022-03-04T12:03:27.319229420Z    -> A non-empty array of
non-empty    strings 2022-03-04T12:03:27.319943436Z See
"/tmp/ng-Tl3lYK/angular-errors.log" for further details.
2022-03-04T12:03:27.334326859Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2022-03-04T12:03:27.334359695Z npm ERR! syscall spawn
2022-03-04T12:03:27.334365753Z npm ERR! file sh
2022-03-04T12:03:27.334370574Z npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2022-03-04T12:03:27.337355865Z npm ERR! sportify@0.0.0 build: `ng    build` 2022-03-04T12:03:27.337415913Z npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2022-03-04T12:03:27.337866101Z npm ERR!
2022-03-04T12:03:27.337888153Z npm ERR! Failed at the sportify@0.0.0
build script. 2022-03-04T12:03:27.337904134Z npm ERR! This is
probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
output above. 2022-03-04T12:03:27.344947118Z
2022-03-04T12:03:27.345024987Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run
can be found in: 2022-03-04T12:03:27.345641712Z npm ERR!
/home/apps/.npm/_logs/2022-03-04T12_03_27_338Z-debug.log
2022-03-04T12:03:27.355261167Z building: exit status 1
2022-03-04T12:03:27.357422543Z [31;1mERROR: [0mfailed to build:
exit status 1 2022-03-04T12:03:37.520418180Z
2022-03-04T12:03:37.520457560Z For documentation on the buildpacks
used to build your app, please see: 2022-03-04T12:03:37.520462908Z
Node.js: https://do.co/apps-buildpack-node
2022-03-04T12:03:37.520469910Z  2022-03-04T12:03:37.520742420Z [31m
! Build failed (145)[0m